# How do I add padding to multiple <span> inside a <li> inside a <pre>

Tags: css

Prettify has spans nested in li's nested inside pre. How can I can get padding between the vertical scroll bar and the text?

http://jsfiddle.net/36xQ9/2/

```
<pre>
<li><span>SDHSAJFKHDSKFSA</span><span>asdasdas</span></li>
</pre>
```

EDIT: I meant the vertical scroll bar.

Comment: don't understand your problem, the horizontal scrollbars are not adjacent to each other

Comment: are you looking like this? http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/36xQ9/3/

Comment: is my above solution work for you?

Comment: Sorry I mean add space between the text and the vertical scroll bar. For example in the JSfiddle, the first pre has padding if you scroll all the way to the right, but the second pre does not.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `.class` in your **css** and add that **css class** in your **span** and **li** tags

```
.space
{
padding:5px;
}


<pre>
<li class="space"><span>SDHSAJFKHDSKFSA</span><span>asdasdas</span></li>
</pre>
```